# Is the question about closed reduction using token-passing nets still open?

Tags: lambda-calculus, interaction-nets

The question about possible implementation of closed reduction using token-passing nets is asked on page 17 in [Token-passing Nets for Functional Languages](http://haslab.uminho.pt/jba/files/07tnfp.pdf) by Jose Bacelar Almeida, Jorge Sousa Pinto, and Miguel Vilaca:

> It would be interesting to explore the applicability of this idea to encode closed reduction as defined by Fernandez et al.

Is this question still open?

Comment: Why don't you as Almeida et al or Fernandez et al, and report back here?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I did try to contact the authors of the article. I will report back here if and when I get any response.

Comment: I just got a reply from Jorge Pinto. He confirmed that this question still remains open. He also noted that approach of token-passing nets may be unsuitable to implement closed reduction, but he is not absolutely sure.